# Solving a functional equation between restriction of a function in an interval

Tags: functional-equations, piecewise-continuity, continuity

I am currently working on this functional equation : find $f$ piecewise-continuous over $[0,b+c]$, and $a,b,c,d>0$ such that

\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace 
\begin{array}{ll}
|f(x)|=1& x\in [0,b+c] \\
f(x)=-1& x \in [a,b] \cup [c,d]  \\
f(x)=f(x+d)&  x \in [0,a] \\
f(x)=-f(x-b)&  x \in [b,b+c]$
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

with $a+d=b+c$, $b-a=d-c$.

Eventually, we assume that $\exists (p,q)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N^*}, d=\frac{p}{q}(b+d)-\frac{1}{q}(b-a)$.

The question is the following :

Which relation between $p$ and $q$ allows to define $f$ everywhere in $[0,b+c]$ without any contradiction?

Any tips or partial results will be appreciated.